# HP Service Manager RESTful Web Service query

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, servicemanager

I want to create a web service(in .net) that would get information from HP Service Manager. I know I can use GET in the RESTful API to get the information I need. I just don't know where to start. I've been trough the documentation but since this is my first time doing this I could use some help to get started.

I have been reading the document [here](http://142.210.56.45:30201/help/en/#webservicesguide/rest.htm%3FTocPath%3DGuides%2520and%2520reference%7CWeb%2520Services%2520Guide%7CRESTful%25C2%25A0API%7C_____0) on the RESTful API. This is some examples

> •/incidents?field1=value1&field2=value2 //Simple
>   Query
>
> •/incidents?query=&sort=number:ascending 
>   //Service Manager Native Query

I have never worked with web service before so it can be hard for me to understand what exactly this means.

Comment: The link you posted did not work for me. Have a look at the `HttpWebRequest` class on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=HttpWebRequest&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=2) and/or Google; for the more recent approach see the [Web API Client Libraries](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Answer (score 0):

There is a .net sample under HP SM installation folder.

Answer (score -2):

I work with the HP Service Manager. Service Manager Native Query is a development language for this application. It is not hard to learn but there are limitations between what you can use in the Service Manager and RESTful API. For example in the SM you may find values into a array field using functions like "isin" ou "index()", these wont work in queries on RESTful API, if you need to return this kind of value, you will need to process it in your script after the query return.

PS: You can mix the Simple query with Service Manager Native Query, if you do it the first one will be ignored.